# Getting CWWKF0044E incompatible feature error using Open Liberty with Maven, but I didn't configure incompatible features

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty, liberty-maven-plugin

When using Open Liberty version 22.0.0.5 and liberty-maven-plugin version 3.3 with a server config (server.xml) configuring just a single feature:

```
    <featureManager>
        <feature>batch-2.0</feature>
    </featureManager>
```

and running "dev mode" (via `mvn liberty:dev`), I get this error as dev mode starts the server:

> [INFO] [ERROR   ] CWWKF0044E: The
> io.openliberty.connectionManager1.0.internal.ee-6.0 and batch-2.0
> features cannot be loaded at the same time. The
> io.openliberty.connectionManager1.0.internal.ee-6.0 feature of Java EE
> 6 is incompatible with the batch-2.0 feature of Jakarta EE 9. The
> batch-2.0 and batch-2.0 configured features include an incompatible
> combination of features. Your configuration is not supported. Update
> the configuration to use features that support either the Java EE or
> Jakarta EE programming models, but not both.
>
> [INFO] [WARNING ] CWWKF0046W: The configuration includes an
> incompatible combination of features. As a result, the feature manager
> did not install any features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### SOLUTION

This is a bug. To resolve, update liberty-maven-plugin to the latest version (or at least to version 3.4, where this was [fixed](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.maven/issues/1236)).

The bug is described [here](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/17843) from the runtime angle, as it was an issue with the way the liberty-maven-plugin queries the Open Liberty runtime for feature versions.